# Forcing TWO footers to the bottom of a page

Tags: html, css, css-position, footer

The site I'm working on now has an interesting layout that I'm having trouble getting just right in CSS. The header and footer span the entire width of the browser window, with the content confined to a 960px wide block - however there's a secondary "internal" footer within this 960px content block. Both the primary footer and this "internal" footer need to be at the bottom of the page. Here's the markup of the website, stripped down to the functional units:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <header></header>
        <section id="content">
            MAIN CONTENT
            <section id="internal-footer"></section>
        </section>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
html{margin:0;padding:0;min-height:100%;height:100%;}
body{margin:0;padding:0;min-height:100%;position:relative;}
header{width:100%;}
footer{width:100%;height:XXXpx;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;}
#content{width:960px;margin:0 auto;position:relative;padding-bottom:(XXX+YYY)px;}
#internal-footer{width:100%;height:YYYpx;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;padding-bottom:XXXpx;}
```

[I created a JSFiddle here (adding background colors and borders, and reducing the width of the content) to demonstrate the issue I'm having.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ds5tX/)

When there is sufficient content, everything works as intended. When there is not enough content, the `#content` section is not stretching and the internal footer is not only lifted, but due to the bottom-padding it is too tall. Of course being too tall isn't a serious issue since I can just set `no-repeat` on the background image and no one is the wiser.

So how can I force the `#content` to stretch to the bottom of the page, without creating a scrollbar, when there is not enough content?

Comment: Is the use of jQuery an option?

Comment: Technically yes, but I would like to avoid JavaScript if it can be done without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the HTML and CSS as below is it helping achieve what you want? Now the internal footer is inside footer and also centered.

```
<footer>
        <section id="internal-footer"></section>
</footer>



#internal-footer{width:300px;padding-bottom:50px!important;background-color:#990;height:50px;margin:-50px auto 0 auto;}
```

**I'm copying your comment with the working fiddler so people can find easily the solution**

*I've resolved the second issue - of the footer content moving. First I had to remove the negative bottom margin on the inner footer (margin:-137px auto 0 auto) then I had to add a margin to the copyright p equal to the footer padding. Update your answer to incorporate the fixes and I can accept it. Here's the final, working, fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/M72fn](http://jsfiddle.net/M72fn)*

Comment: This almost worked! The problem was that the internal footer appeared "within" the footer (overlapping it) instead of above it, in the content area. I resolved this by changing your margins to: `margin:-50px auto` and removing the `padding-bottom`. I think this is working, but I will test it on the main site.

Comment: Ran into two problems. First, I had to increase the negative margin by the `padding-top` on the footer (my footer on the live site had a 20px padding and the internal footer was 117px tall, so I used `margin:-137px auto`). Second, and I haven't solved this yet - all the content of the footer has been moved. My footer has a simple `p` element containing copyright text, and this `p` was moved above the internal footer for some reason - floating over the main content.

Comment: @stevendesu If you use `css` `box-sizing: border-box;` you won't have to worry about calcing margins and all that jazz. :] Other ext needed are `-webkit-` and `-moz`.

Comment: Look at the new solution this will work 100% (i think / i hope) :)

Comment: Your new solution hides any content that extends beyond the window height

Comment: If you return to your old solution, I've resolved the second issue - of the footer content moving. First I had to remove the negative bottom margin on the inner footer (`margin:-137px auto 0 auto`) then I had to add a margin to the copyright `p` equal to the footer padding. Update your answer to incorporate the fixes and I can accept it. Here's the final, working, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M72fn/

Comment: One thing I do want to note about the final, working solution was that the `#content` didn't actually stretch all the way to the footer so the background of the page should match the background of the content in order to avoid a strange "bar" between the content and the footer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you should use javascript. Here is how I would do that with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(($(window).height()-100)>$('#content').height()){
        $('#content').height($(window).height()-200);
    }
});
```

[and the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ds5tX/2/)

Comment: You would need to add a resize listener for this to be a reasonable solution. Besides, the requested layout is achievable without the need for scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Your content area needs to be 100% of the available height. This can be done by positioning `header` absolutely (as you have the footer) and then making `#content` 100% high with padding to allow for the header and footers:

```
header {width:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;...}
#content {display:block; min-height:100%; padding:50px 0 100px 0; ...}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ds5tX/3/

Comment: @stevendesu. You're right. Your solution of having one footer that *looks* like 2 is probably the way to go.